# Reals numbers that sum to 0

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots{},a_k$ be real numbers such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots{}+a_k=0$ and $a_1\le a_2\le \cdots{}\le a_k$. Prove that $$a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots{}+a_k^2+ka_1a_k\le 0.$$

**Progress:** For any $m$ and $n$ we must have $a_1a_k\le a_ma_n$ and we also have the relation $$a_1^2+a_2^2\cdots{}+a_k^2=-2\sum_{1\le m<n\le k} a_ma_n.$$
Proceeding by contradiction seems to be the best possible way, but I'm finding it difficult to prove the statement. Any hints or solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a_1 \leq a_i \leq a_k$ for all $i$,  we obtain:
$$(a_k - a_i)(a_i - a_1) \ge 0.$$
Thus,
$$0\leq\sum_{i=1}^k(a_k - a_i)(a_i - a_1)=\sum_{i=1}^k(a_k a_i - a_k a_1 - a_i^2 + a_i a_1)=$$
$$ =-(a_1^2 + a_2^2 +... + a_k^2) - ka_1 a_k$$
and we are done!

Comment: Nice and short solution!